# It is coming soon!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What would be great right now? (*The answer is a phrase)*!**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What would be great now is

> a slice of pi.

It is coming soon

> on the 14th of March, known as "Pi Day" because if one applies the degenerate and perverted convention used in the United States whereby dates are written month/day/year, that day is 3/14 and the decimal expansion of pi begins 3.14.

The diagram shows

> the first however-many-it-is digits of pi, written in a clockwise spiral out from the centre, with prime digits (2,3,5,7) obscured in red and a *slice of pi* replaced with question-marks.

Thus:

> ```
>             -----1---6---4---0---6-----
>            /                           `.
>           /  9---3---9---9---3---7---5   `.
>          |   |                         \   `.
>          8   6   6---2---6---4---3---3   1   |
>          |   |   |                   |   |   |
>      0   7   1   4   2---6---5---3   8   0   2
>      |   |   |   |   |           |   |   |   |
>      8   0   7   8   9   3---1   5   3   5   8
>      |   |   |   |   |       |   |   |   |   |
>      2   3   9   3   5---1---4   8   2   8   6
>      |   |   |   |               |   |   |   |
>      6   2   1   2---3---9---7---9   7   2   2
>      |   |   |                       |   |   |
>      |   9   4---8---8---2---0---5---9   0   |
>       `.   \                           /    /
>         `.   5---4---4---9---4---7---9    ,'
>           `.                            ,'
>             `----8---9---9---8---0-----'
> ```

A couple of further notes provided by OP in comments:

> the digits are in a s-PI-ral, and those *prime* digits have been covered up with the *primary* colour red.

Comment: Fantastic! This is the right answer. I hope this puzzle wasn’t too easy and you had fun solving it.

Comment: Even if you use the excellent format YYYY-MM-DD, it's an appropriate name for the day.

Comment: @msh210 what are your honest thoughts about this puzzle I would appreciate some feedback. I am not sure why this got downvoted.

Comment: @msh210 True. I did wonder about mentioning that -- I'm a fan of the ISO8601 format myself -- but I'm pretty sure it's the dreadful US convention that's responsible for the name.

Comment: (And I don't think there's anything wrong with the puzzle. Occasional downvotes are just a fact of life.)